# publishing ASP.NET MVC 5 to distant iis server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, iis-6

I published my asp.net MVC 5 Web application into IIS Server, but after loading page from browser, it shown only shared View layout and the Default Error View in shared Folder, see the picture below.

[image]

In each view i navigate to,
The Left bar you see in blue, it developed in shared layout view, inside main view it show the error page in shared folder
I have IIS Web Server v 6.0
my app is under Asp.net 4.5 and MVC 5

Any solution please

Answer (score 0):

In my view there is an issue with your RouteConfig, or you don't have the permission to access to the IIS folder.

Leo

Comment: In case of first issue RouteConfig, what's the solution ?

Comment: @Sylver If you can provide some code about your RouteConfig and Controllers, i will be more clear and maybe help you